# Load share across 3 USB-C PD connections

Tags: power, batteries, usb-c

I have 3, 20V 100W USB-C PD power supplies, which are basically a USB-C power bank connected to [3 of these USB-C triggers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0953HKPWG). I would like to spread the load of my project out among all 3 power supplies, preferably using off-the-shelf parts.

My current idea is to connect each trigger to its own [20V Boost converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09245FZ3X) (ensure we have 20V even if we plug in a different power bank that doesn't support 20V), then connect the output of each converter to [its own ideal diode](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SGH7BP3), then finally connect the "out" terminals of the 3 ideal diodes together, add a power switch, and hopefully have an output of 20V with the power draw spread out across all 3 power banks. If I understood it correctly, the maximum current from this would be the sum of all 3 supplies, so if each power bank supplied 100W, I should be able to theoretically draw 300W or 15A at 20V (minus the 5% or so efficiency loss per step).

Diagram:
[image]

Is this plan feasible to do what I want, or is there a better way to do it? Are my assumptions valid? I also want to be able to remove/replace 1-2 power banks (leaving at least one plugged in) without a loss of power (the project can run on 1 power bank, things just get really hot if left that way for a long time & it dies quickly). Would this be able to do that?

Would this be better if instead I took out the 100W boost converters and instead put a 300W boost converter after the diode? I read that putting the converter after the diode is recommended, although if any power bank didn't support 20V then this would result in that power bank being excluded?

Comment: The current will not distribute evenly between the sources, so you can't add current like that. If someone plugs in a 5/12v USB source the available current will be much lower as well, so  you won't be able to get 5A out. What is your actual load?

Comment: @user1850479 The current actual load should be around 80W. Each power bank is labeled as 100W (so probably a little less in reality after accounting for efficiency). Currently if I run it on one battery, it'll work but it'll eventually overheat, and the battery dies very quickly. I don't need anywhere near 300W, I just want to know I'm not close to overloading my parts, to not have to manually swap out batteries (and if there's a large buffer for future feature additions, that's just a bonus).

Comment: The easiest and best solution is to buy a single power supply that can handle your load for as long as required. Otherwise, you can connect power supplies with diodes and as one fails the next will take over. The boost converters though are useless since you won't get 80w unless the source is 20v.

Comment: It is possible to link multiple boost converters together to share the current evenly, but it requires special design.